# No idea what to do with a pure php page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to implement an already coded image upload system which has been written purely in php. I have a html website but did not know that I could direct users to a pure php page. Surely it would just show in a browser as coding. How do I make this pure php webpage into a html webpage? I am new to web design so any help is muchly appreciated.

Would I have to implement it as an iframe within a html page?

Thanks

Comment: `surely it would just show in a browser as coding` is not correct.  As long as your php pages are coming from a web server with php installed, it will not render any of the php code, it will execute the php and output any generated html, if you developing locally then you may see the php code depending on your environment

Comment: also, since you're new to web design, when you're testing this, note that you have to NAVIGATE to the php page by ip address. if you try to just double click the file to open it, you'll get a blank page or some strange results if there's html mixed in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of the PHP program just needs to be an HTML document (unless you override it, it will output a `text/html` content-type so you only have to provide the HTML document itself).

There is no need to involve iframes.

> Surely it would just show in a browser as coding.

No, unless you are using a server which does not support PHP or have not configured it correctly, the PHP will be executed on the server and the output delivered to the browser.

Comment: there are some exceptions. for example, if php is not enabled and you're using textareas, any php code put inside the "value" tag will be presented on screen

Comment: @JeffHawthorne — that would fall under "using a server which does not support PHP or have not configured it correctly"

Comment: @JeffHawthorne, `<input type='text' value='<?php echo "10"; ?>'>` Do you mean the textbox will show as `<?php echo "10" ?>` in the browser?

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS — Only if the PHP wasn't executed by the server.

Comment: @Quentin: Yeah I know, the question was to Jeff, he said so.

Comment: right. a common mistake with new programmers is they'll double click a php file to open it, because they're used to that working with html files. but when you do that, the server doesn't realize it's supposed to execute the code, so it ends up outputting some of it

Comment: If you double click the file in your file manager then your browser (or editor) will open the file from the file system instead of asking the server for it. The server outputs nothing.

Comment: @Quentin unless, as i mentioned, you have php code inside text areas, in which case the code will be output

Answer (score 0):

1. Install PHP with Apache. If you are feeling tough to install it manual, go to [www.apachefriends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org), find the suitable version of XAMPP for you, download and install in in your machine.
2. Make sure you install the Apache service. This will make Apache to run whenever you boot your system.
3. Move your PHP, HTML and all associated CSS, JS files to the following folder path, **C:\xampp\htdocs\YOUR_FOLDER_NAME**
4. In your browser, you can open the files as `http://localhost/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/FILENAME.php`.

Now you will see it as processed HTML page. This will work for both your HTML and PHP pages.